# Serialize / deserialize with multiple LocalStrategy PassportJs / ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am starting with PassportJs/ExpressJs application for authentication 
 i have two different model for User and Admin
 **Here is passport.js code**

```
passport.use('admin', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(email, password, done) {
    var adminflag = 'admin';
    console.log('---------------------in admin')

    db.adminUser.find({ where: { email: email }}).success(function(user) {
      if (!user) {
        done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user' });
      } else if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
        done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password'});
      } else {
        console.log('Login (local) : { id: ' + user.id + ', username: ' + user.username + ' }');
        done(null, user);
      }
    }).error(function(err){
      done(err);
    });
  }
));
```

LocalStrategy for user

```
passport.use('user', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(email, password, done) {
    console.log('---------------------in user')
    var userflag = 'user';
    db.User.find({ where: { email: email }}).success(function(admin) {
      if (!admin) {
        done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user' });
      } else if (!admin.authenticate(password)) {
        done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password'});
      } else {
        console.log('Login (local) : { id: ' + admin.id + ', username: ' + admin.username + ' }');
        done(null, admin);
      }
    }).error(function(err){
      done(err);
    });
  }
));
```

so My Question is that how can i write serializeUser/deserializeUser for admin and user

```
passport.serializeUser(function(admin, done) {
    if (admin.isSuperAdmin == 0 || admin.isSuperAdmin == 1 ) {
        flag = true;
           done(null, admin.id);       
           console.log('----------------------ADMIN');
    }else{
        flag = false;
        console.log('------------------USER');
        done(null, admin.id);       
    }; 
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id ,done) {
        db.User.find({where: {id: id}}).success(function(admin){
        console.log('Session: { id: ' + user.id + ', username: ' + user.username + ' }');
            done(null, admin);
        }).error(function(err){
            done(err, null);
        });        
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`serializeUser` isn't limited to just scalar values, so you can serialize an object that contains the type (admin or plain user):

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  var isAdmin = user.isSuperAdmin === 0 || user.isSuperAdmin === 1;
  return done(null, { id : user.id, isAdmin : isAdmin };    
});
```

In your deserialize function, you can check for that type:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  var collection = user.isAdmin ? db.adminUser : db.User;
  collection.find({ id : user.id }, ...);
});
```

However, if possible I would consider merging those two collections into one `User` collection and use a flag to signify if a user is admin or not.

Comment: deserializeUser  method is going in loop not getting callback

Comment: So the user cannot be deserialized? If not, does the `user` object look okay? Which session store are you using?

Comment: user object is look okay but after login it didn't get callback

Comment: can you suggest in following code `passport.deserializeUser(function(user ,done) {
        if(user.isAdmin){
            db.adminUser.find({where: {id: user.id}}).success(function(admin){
                done(null, admin);
            }).error(function(err){
                done(err, null);
            });
        } else{            
            db.User.find({where: {id: user.id}}).success(function(user){
                done(null, user);
            }).error(function(err){
                done(err, null);
            });
        };
});`

Comment: In above code i am getting error  **throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 AND `adminUsers`.`id`  true LIMIT 1' at line 1**

Comment: You should rewrite `deserializeUser` so it fits your database. I made some assumptions on how it would work, but those assumptions may be incorrect.