# Multiple models in passport.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I have two types of account on my website:

Admin and User.

The admin will access to the administration portal and will use credentials and passport.js to authenticate.

The user will access to his account. He could list the products ... He will not have access to the admin portal but to the front.

So to summarize the admin account can add products, descriptions, manage stocks and the user will have an account to buy the products (ecommerce).

Now my question is that the authentication protocol is the same but my models are different.

So what is the best way to allow passport.js to authenticate my two accounts?

I need to pass the model to passport.js.

The solutions I am thinking about are:

1. Have a user base model and inherit the base model in my Admin and User models. But I do not know how to do this.
2. Pass the model type I will use to passport.js. But how to do that?
3. Create an independent authentication system for every models. But it will complicate the code to do exactly the same things. Duplication and I hate this. :)

If you have other ideas or best practices and can help I would really appreciate.

Thanks,

Comment: passport is just the "are the credentials correct" layer, it doesn't care about models. Your handling should be of the form "request comes in, passport verifies they are authenticated, your own code verifies that this authenticated user is of a type that is allowed to call this route, appropriate content is then served". Somewhere you're storing which user is of which type (like in your user db, where each user could have a type flag), and you look that up after they pass passport's authentication check.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I do not get it. In my passport I have:  Admin.create({ ...  to create the admin user. So I need to change the model to create the user User.create({ ... Is there a way to do it dynamically. Would you have an example of code for your solution? Thanks!

Comment: Try to read following question and aswer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864213/serialize-deserialize-with-multiple-localstrategy-passportjs-expressjs

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is correct, passport is only the authentication part of the puzzle, the problem you're describing has to do with authorization. Are there any differences between your Admin and User models or is it only a matter of permissions? Instead of two different models, maybe you could have just one `User` model with a `role` property, and use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-roles to determine what admins and users can and can't do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the problem? You can store in your DB different roles for users, like:
1 - admin
2 - moderator
0 - user (Default)

And after authorization (you can use single route for admins and users in this case if you want) you can check in your routes a permissions:

```
app.get('/admin/dashboard', isAdmin, function(req, res, next) {
  // you will get inside only if user is authentificated and has role of admin
  // otherwise he will be redirected to the mainpage '/'
  res.send('Hi, admin');
});

function isAdmin(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
       // if user is admin, go next
       if (req.user.role == 1) {
         return next();
       }
    }
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: problem with this strategy i ran into was conditional validations, validations for one user type are different for another type. so now you have to weird conditional validations which is pain